# java.lang.StackOverflowError when pressing FX ComboBox on Android

Tags: android, javafx, stack-overflow, javafxports

When using JavaFXPorts on Android (Android 4.1.1 on Asus Transformer Prime TF201 tablet), a java.lang.StackOverflowError is thrown when pressing on a ComboBox (see below the top stacks of the stacktrace).

It happens in a ComboBox in my FX application and is also 100% reproducible with the ComboBox example that is in Ensemble. In other words: can't use JavaFX ComboBox.

I'm aware of the Android stack size limit posted in many forums and there are various suggestions on what to do when it happens with Android UI and Android APIs. However, can't find a relevant idea to apply when using JavaFX UI and JavaFXPorts.

Any idea for a fix\tweak\workaround would be much appreciated.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32212): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
E/AndroidRuntime(32212): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime(32212):        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3422)
E/AndroidRuntime(32212):        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
E/AndroidRuntime(32212):        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1516)
E/AndroidRuntime(32212):        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
E/AndroidRuntime(32212):        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
E/AndroidRuntime(32212):        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
E/AndroidRuntime(32212):        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the `java.custom.properties` file, and include in it this property:

```
monocle.stackSize=128000
```

You can override other system properties as well by including them with their new values.

Put the file at the root of your classpath, e.g. in the folder `src/android/resources` of your project.

You can find this FAQ <s>here</s> [here](http://gluonhq.com/knowledge-base/get-java-lang-stackoverflowexception-running-application-device/) and all the documentation for JavaFXPorts [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/).

Check if this solves your exception.

Comment: Thanks Jose, that solved the issue in a one swift move.
+1

Comment: I had a similar issue with a Tableview, and this resolved it +1, sadly FAQ link above is dead, closet link I can find is http://gluonhq.com/knowledge-base/get-java-lang-stackoverflowexception-running-application-device/

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Indeed, that's the correct link. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @José Pereda sorry but where I created this file what directory of my project?

Comment: As I is said: in the folder `/src/android/resources` of your project, or `/src/main/resources` if you want to add some other properties common for all platforms.