# Gluon applicaiton javafx crash on selecting date picker in android

Tags: javafx, gluon

My gluon application project gets crashed on android device ie my phone,while selecting date picker but when I run the applicaiton on my tablet there is no problem and everyting works fine,here Is stack trace of my application

1. How to fix this error?

> 03-26 20:04:13.829: V/FXEntity(6986): Called notify_hideIME
>       03-26 20:04:13.829: V/FXEntity(6986): Done Calling notify_hideIME
>       03-26 20:04:13.829: V/FXEntity(6986): Called notify_showIME
>       03-26 20:04:13.839: V/FXEntity(6986): Done calling notify_showIME
>       03-26 20:04:14.039: D/dalvikvm(6986): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1719K, 27% free 13668K/18695K, paused 16ms+3ms, total 122ms
>       03-26 20:04:18.729: I/System.out(6986): Login sucessfullSTAFF_ADVISOR
>       03-26 20:04:18.749: W/dalvikvm(6986): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 37190: Ljava/util/WeakHashMap;.getOrDefault
>   (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       03-26 20:04:18.759: W/dalvikvm(6986): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 37190: Ljava/util/WeakHashMap;.getOrDefault
>   (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       03-26 20:04:18.989: I/System.out(6986): SATURDAY
>       03-26 20:04:18.989: W/dalvikvm(6986): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls-nt_en_GB'
>       03-26 20:04:18.989: W/dalvikvm(6986): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls-nt_en'
>       03-26 20:04:18.989: W/dalvikvm(6986): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls-nt'
>       03-26 20:04:19.019: I/System.out(6986): 320.0  509.0
>       03-26 20:04:19.019: V/FXEntity(6986): Called notify_hideIME
>       03-26 20:04:19.019: V/FXEntity(6986): Done Calling notify_hideIME
>       03-26 20:04:19.409: D/dalvikvm(6986): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1134K, 23% free 14419K/18695K, paused 14ms+7ms, total 122ms
>       03-26 20:04:19.409: D/dalvikvm(6986): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
>       03-26 20:04:19.779: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 337
>       03-26 20:04:19.799: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 337
>       03-26 20:04:19.819: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 338
>       03-26 20:04:19.839: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 339
>       03-26 20:04:19.849: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 339
>       03-26 20:04:19.849: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 339
>       03-26 20:04:20.069: I/System.out(6986): 6
>       03-26 20:04:20.069: V/FXEntity(6986): Called notify_showIME
>       03-26 20:04:20.069: V/FXEntity(6986): Done calling notify_showIME
>       03-26 20:04:20.289: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:20.289: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/System.out(6986): don't add points, primary = -1
>       03-26 20:04:20.299: I/System.out(6986): enternull
>       03-26 20:04:20.329: V/FXEntity(6986): Called notify_hideIME
>       03-26 20:04:20.339: V/FXEntity(6986): Done Calling notify_hideIME
>       03-26 20:04:21.819: D/dalvikvm(6986): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1382K, 20% free 14963K/18695K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 89ms
>       03-26 20:04:30.639: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 216
>       03-26 20:04:30.639: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.639: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.669: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 216
>       03-26 20:04:30.679: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 216
>       03-26 20:04:30.699: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 217
>       03-26 20:04:30.719: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 217
>       03-26 20:04:30.729: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 215
>       03-26 20:04:30.749: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 216
>       03-26 20:04:30.749: E/FXEntity(6986): call native MultitouchEvent, density = 1.5, touchXs0 = 216
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.829: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: I/GLASS(6986): Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: I/GLASS(6986): Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: I/System.out(6986): don't add points, primary = -1
>       03-26 20:04:30.839: V/FXEntity(6986): Called notify_showIME
>       03-26 20:04:30.849: V/FXEntity(6986): Done calling notify_showIME
>       03-26 20:04:31.569: D/dalvikvm(6986): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1691K, 19% free 15320K/18695K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 93ms
>       03-26 20:04:31.569: D/dalvikvm(6986): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986): java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.lambda$static$18(Node.java:9323)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.access$lambda$4(Node.java)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node$$Lambda$5.getGeomBounds(Unknown Source)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.effect.Effect.getInputBounds(Effect.java:327)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow.impl_getBounds(DropShadow.java:694)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3590)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3623)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3484)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1516)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1588)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1588)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1588)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.lambda$static$18(Node.java:9323)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.access$lambda$4(Node.java)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node$$Lambda$5.getGeomBounds(Unknown Source)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.effect.Effect.getInputBounds(Effect.java:327)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow.impl_getBounds(DropShadow.java:694)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3590)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3623)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3484)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1516)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1516)
>       03-26 20:04:31.679: E/AndroidRuntime(6986):   at javafx.s
>       03-26 20:04:31.899: V/FXActivity(6986): onPause
>       03-26 20:04:32.609: V/FXEntity(6986): Called Surface destroyed
>       03-26 20:04:32.609: V/FXActivity native(6986): [JVDBG] SURFACE created native android window at 0x0, surface = 0x0
>       03-26 20:04:32.609: I/GLASS(6986): Native code is notified that surface has changed (repaintall)!
>       03-26 20:04:33.449: V/FXActivity(6986): onStop
>       03-26 20:04:33.449: V/FXActivity(6986): onDestroy

Comment: Try this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/34752754/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-pressing-fx-combobox-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752754/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-pressing-fx-combobox-on-android)

Comment: Thank you that fixed the error