# JavaFX throws stackoverflow error

Tags: javafx-8, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have this method in my `Dialog` class:

```
public static void hide(){
    isOpen = false;
    Main.PAGE.getChildren().removeAll(Main.PAGE.getChildren());
    Main.PAGE.getChildren().add(Main.ROOT);
}
```

I tried to run it in **Samsung TabS** and **LG Leon** phone and it worked but when I tried to run it in my **Samsung GT-N5100** it throws a **StackOverFlow Error**.

**Why?**

Comment: This might be related to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752754/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-pressing-fx-combobox-on-android

Comment: (1) Have you tried replacing `Main.PAGE.getChildren().removeAll(Main.PAGE.getChildren())` with `Main.PAGE.getChildren().clear()`? (Most probably unrelated to the problem) (2) It would help if you provided the actual stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, I tried it, but it didn't worked! Thanks anyway.  :)

Comment: @JoeriSykora, thank you sir! it worked!    :)