# javafxports: javafx context menu on android device

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, contextmenu, javafxports

I've got a problem with display **JavaFX** context menu on android devices.It works fine on desktop, but on android the app crashes.

Java snippet responsible for showing my example context menu when a user presses a button:

```
public class MainButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    try{
        Controls.addDebugLine(event.getEventType().toString());
        Button button = (Button) event.getTarget();
        System.out.println(button);
        button.getContextMenu().show(button, Side.RIGHT, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Controls.addDebugLine(e.getMessage());         
    }
}
```

android log:

```
11-11 13:43:33.812: E/AndroidRuntime(16742): Process: pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main, PID: 16742
11-11 13:43:33.832: W/ActivityManager(858):   Force finishing activity pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity
11-11 13:43:33.832: V/ActivityManager(858): Moving to PAUSING: ActivityRecord{42d29480 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity t62 f}
11-11 13:43:34.053: V/ActivityManager(858): Moving to PAUSED: ActivityRecord{42d29480 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity t62 f} (pause complete)
11-11 13:43:34.053: V/ActivityManager(858): Moving to STOPPING: ActivityRecord{42d29480 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity t62 f} (finish requested)
11-11 13:43:34.703: V/ActivityManager(858): Moving to FINISHING: ActivityRecord{42d29480 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity t62 f}
11-11 13:43:34.703: V/ActivityManager(858): Moving to DESTROYING: ActivityRecord{42d29480 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity t62 f} (destroy requested)
11-11 13:43:34.733: I/ActivityManager(858): Process pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main (pid 16742) has died.
11-11 13:43:34.733: V/ActivityManager(858): Moving to DESTROYED: ActivityRecord{42d29480 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity t62 f} (removed from history)
11-11 13:43:34.733: V/ActivityManager(858): Moving to DESTROYED: ActivityRecord{42d29480 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity t62 f} (cleaning up)
11-11 13:43:34.733: I/WindowState(858): WIN DEATH: Window{435301b0 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
11-11 13:43:34.733: W/WindowManager(858): Force-removing child win Window{436d5a10 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{435301b0 u0 pl.siemaeniu500.wszywka.main/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
```

Comment: Can you post (inline) your build.gradle script, and can you get a full stacktrace that shows the exception? The log doesn't show anything relevant. Run `adb logcat -v threadtime` and post the stacktrace due to the crash.

Comment: Yes of course: error: http://pastebin.com/aPuiY2YP   gradle:http://pastebin.com/4kmWReUe

Comment: The well known stackoverflow exception has an easy solution. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752754/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-pressing-fx-combobox-on-android). What is your device?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40548417/edit) your post to put the code and messages in your question. We shouldn't have to go to external sites to understand your question, the SO search can't find questions on external sites, and if the link goes dead your question will no longer make any sense.