# Gluon Mobile for Android = StackOverflowError device dependent

Tags: android, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I have successfully ported a javafx app from desktop to iOS and now I'm working on the Android port.

I'm using jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10

One of my views gives a stack overflow in a virtual device but not another.

Is there any way to indicate when building the application for Android a minimum stack size? How are this kind of issues typically approached?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1588)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1516)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1588)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1588)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1516)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
        at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3593)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3623)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3484)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1588)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
        at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
        at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1724)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1516)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
        at javafx.scene.Nod
```

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34753152/3956070).

Comment: Very big thanks Jose, this solved the issue and now my app works on both iOS and Android, mostly thanks to your support. Still feels like magic to me since I can't find a deeper explanation. Regarding the links in your post, one is broken and in the javafxports I can't find mention of anything about the stack size in android. Can you tell me if 128000 is in bytes? Accepts other values? Other interesting links?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.StackOverflowError when pressing FX ComboBox on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752754/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-pressing-fx-combobox-on-android)